# Is there a specific set of ports to forward for MH3U packet utility?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

I keep running into 106-0612 errors whenever I try to connect to rooms in the packet utility and some of the proposed solutions are to forward ports for the Wii U.  However, I can't find what specific ports to forward.  Some posts are saying to forward 1 through 7540, but that seems like major overkill.  Is there a specific set of ports that the Wii U uses?